# pickle "Running out of input" on a file just pickled

Tags: python, pickle

I have a problem in my code, where unpickling causes the "Ran out of input" error every single time. To test this, i ran a little thing in the command prompt

```
Python 3.6.1 (v3.6.1:69c0db5, Mar 21 2017, 17:54:52) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pickle
>>> with open('C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/testing/playerlist.txt', 'wb') as f:
...     pickle.dump({"foo": "bar"}, f)
...
>>> with open('C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/testing/playerlist.txt', 'rb') as f:
...     print(f.read())
...     print(pickle.loads(f.read()))
...
b'\x80\x03}q\x00X\x03\x00\x00\x00fooq\x01X\x03\x00\x00\x00barq\x02s.'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
EOFError: Ran out of input
>>>
```

This code worked for me before, but suddenly does not. Is there some part of pickle I am misunderstanding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print(f.read())
```

Read all the input already, which means that the file pointer is at the end of the file. So when you later did,

```
 print(pickle.loads(f.read()))
```

There’s nothing left for the pointer to read.

You can either remove the first `print(f.read())` or add a `f.seek(0)` after `print(f.read())` to move the file pointer to the beginning of the file.

---

Side note:

Just like `pickle.dump(dict, f)` you can also use `pickle.load(f)` to load the file directly from the file object without needing to use `pickle.loads(f.read())`.

Answer (score 0):

`f.read()` exhausts the file iterator when you call it in `print()`, so there is no data when you call it again within `pickle.loads()`. You would need to rewind the pointer with `f.seek(0)`, or capture it in a variable which you use both for print and for load.